# Some new graph operations in graph theory.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I was just going through following link on wiki about the graph operations:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations.

Just curious to know if there any other graph operations that are not defined in the above link. It would be kind of you to help me. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Of course there will be other operations not on the wikipedia page. And new operations can be invented at any time.

Comment: Before some time i have to do with operations from one graph G with N vertices to N graphs H1,H2,..., HN. I don't know if this would also useful for you. Daniel

Comment: @DanielPol What was the operation name? It may be helpful to me. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: This was a operation invented by me in order to establish canonizations of graphs. In this operation, each Hi graph is a mixed graph , it is a DAG (directed acyclic graph) but with undirected edges at each level. This graph Hi is obtained be using a each v[i] from graph G, and sort all vertices to this vertex v[i] by distances. For example if a distance from a v[i] to a vertex "b" is 1, then we will have a arrow from v[i] to "b". If a vertex c have distance n, and a vertex d, have a distance n+1, then we will have c-->d. And all connexions between vertices which have a difference of 1 of

Comment: distance, form a DAG, all another edges (from original graph G) which have same distance to v[i] will have in our mixed graph  a undirected edge. I call this graphs H1,H2, ..., Hn, DAGH's (because "hybrid DAG's"). I call this operation : "graph to DAGH's" operation (by distances). If you want i can send you a pdf with graph examples and more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an explicit example of a graph operation not (currently) listed on the wiki page, consider the *wreath product*. While usually defined for algebraic objects like groups, it's also possible to define a wreath product for graphs. The following definition can be found in [1] which goes on to further generalize the operation to a *generalized wreath product*.

> Let $\mathcal{G}_1 = (V_1, E_1)$ and $\mathcal{G}_2 = (V_2, E_2)$  be two finite graphs. The wreath product $\mathcal{G}_1 \wr \mathcal{G}_2$ is the graph with vertex set $V_2^{V_1} \times V_1 = \{(f, v) \vert f:V_1 \rightarrow V_2, v\in V_1\}$  where two vertices $(f,v)$ and $(f', v')$ are connected by an edge if:
>
> 1) (edges of the first type) either $v=v'=: \overline{v}$ and $f(w) = f(w')$ for every $w \neq \overline{v}$, and $f(\overline{v}) \sim f'(\overline{v})$ in $\mathcal{G}_2$;
>
> 2) (edges of the second type) or $f(w) = f'(w)$, for every $w\in V_1$, and $v\sim v'$ in $\mathcal{G}_1$.

EDITED TO ADD:

Another graph operation not currently listed on the wiki page is *[transitive closure](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transitive-closure-of-a-graph/)*. This one is a little surprising to me since this one is much more elementary than the wreath product.

1. Donno, Alfredo. "[Generalized wreath products of graphs and groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7085)." Graphs and Combinatorics 31.4 (2015): 915-926.

Comment: Wow. That's a new graph product I just heard. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Many years  ago I had to do some work with *[hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph)* which you won't find at the referred Wiki-page with focus *operation* on graphs. It is instead considered to be  some kind of *generalisation* of graphs.

> Maybe you are also interested in the Wiki-page *[extensions and generalisations of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Extensions_and_generalizations_of_graphs)*,  since for instance *[coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)* or *[labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_labeling)* of graphs might also be considered as  *operations* on graphs.

Comment: Thank you sir for providing a new topic in this field.

Comment: @monalisa: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Wikipedia has all of them in the article, if not then at least one guy would have added it.

Comment: No, there is no reason to believe this.

Comment: Wikipedia may have all the ones that appear in popular graph theory textbooks. But if I write a research paper for which I need to invent a new graph operation, I'm not going to go put it on Wikipedia.